# Postgresql: How to extract tje text after last numerical chars

Tags: regex, postgresql, parsing

Address files is gather in one line but need to be reported as Street, number, apartment. ex: `"Main street 1 B"`. The data can be input a bit as customers feels so there will not be a space necessarily and maybe there might not even be a number nor an apartment.

I can get the street like that: `trim(substring(column_name from '[^\d]+'))`
the street number drop all the letters: `regexp_replace(column_name :: text, '\D', '', 'g')` ->> maybe not very accurate

But I am struggling on getting the apartment where the assumption is: whatever comes after the last numerical value.

Comment: Most such issues are usually solved by the Regular Expression. However, there should be a large number of sample data to solve the issue exactly. If you have the opportunity, you will write several sample data from those addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract text after last digit you can use this regex :

```
SELECT trim(substring('Main street 1 B' from '.*[\d ](.*)'));
```